# IF sheet name contains specific text?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to do a bit of fail-safeing to check if the correct sheet is active before running the rest of the macro. The sheet is always the final sheet and it always contains a specific string but it also contains a number and that can vary (e.g. Field Map 1, Field Map 2, Field Map 3 etc), so the exact string is not always the same. I just need to know that the active sheet contains "Field Map" in the name regardless of the number.

I need something like:

```
Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

If Not Activesheet.Name contains "Field Map" Then
Msgbox ("Sheet not found")
Exit Sub
End If
```

I know the "Contains" bit doesn't exist but hopefully that explains what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Why does it have to be **ActiveSheet**?  Why not just look for the sheet containing the relevant name?

Comment: Running a macro does generally not have to have a specific sheet selected. Just refer to it using explicit references.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Because there will be several with that same name but different numbers on the end and I need it to select the last one. I suppose, ideally I would have it to look for the sheet that contains "Field Map" AND also has the highest number. But I thought that sounded more complicated?

Comment: It would be much more robust to do it that way.  It's generally not a good thing to rely on Active Sheet, Selection, ActiveCell , etc

Comment: @RonRosenfeld To be honest I would much prefer to do it that way as it would eliminate the issue of it not being the last sheet. But I don't know how to get it to find all the sheets that contain "Field Map" AND select the one with the highest number. Would I have to loop it through all sheets? (bit of an amateur here)

Comment: Yes, but that's simple.  I see @JvdV has posted an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you should refrain from using `.Select` and the likes as much as possible. It might just be enough to get the appropriate sheet in a variable. Something to consider might be the following using an `ArrayList` object which can be sorted and reversed to get the maximum integer used creating worksheets that are named `"Field Map ***":

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arrList As Object: Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name Like "Field Map*" Then arrList.Add Int(Split(ws.Name, " Map ")(1))
Next

If arrList.Count > 0 Then
    arrList.Sort
    arrList.Reverse
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Map " & arrList(0))
Else
    MsgBox "No sheet found!"
End If

End Sub
```

Now you can use `ws` further on in your code if you wish. If you must use `.Select` then change that line into `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Map " & arrList(0)).Select`

Note that I assumed your sheets are called `Field Map 1`, `Field Map 2` etc etc.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the slow reply. I was struggling to get it working. It seems to work fine in a new document but its not working through my userForm? Am I missing something? I'm using a userForm as there are several different macros that I want to keep together. Each activated via a Private Sub  commandbutton_Click ()

Comment: Well, you could make it a callable function? Otherwise run it on your initialize event

Comment: It just seems to completely ignore the ArrayList and go straight to "No sheet found!". This is probably just my lack of experience here. Is it the userForm that's causing the issues?

Comment: I just changed ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook and its works fine :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use InStr function

```
    If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "Field Map") Then
    'Your Code
Else
    MsgBox ("Sheet Not Found"): Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: `InStr` returns an `Integer`, not a `Boolean`.

Comment: So you can add >=1 at the end to make it `Boolean` like that `If InStr(ActiveSheet.Name, "Field Map") >= 1 Then`

Comment: You should. Automatic data conversion is a source of so many errors (and questions on SO)

Comment: To be fair, any number `<> 0` is `True`